# Creating a function using two or more lists

Tags: python, list, function

```
 lista = [100, 200, 300]
 listb = [10, 20, 30]
```

Using python 2.7, if I want to define a function that would take the first element from list a and add it to the first element of list b, and then iterate through the lists in this manner, how would I do so? Is there a way to set up the function that it could do this for any number of lists?

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a code writing service, start by writing a function that takes your lists as parameters and go from there.

Answer (score 4):

You can use list comprehension in combination with `zip`. `zip` combines the two lists, allowing you to sum its elements:

```
[a+b for a,b in zip(lista, listb)]
```

Your method would simply look like this

```
def method(lista,listb):
    return [a+b for a,b in zip(lista, listb)]
```

Or if you prefer the MapReduce paradigm you can also use `map` in combination with the `add` operator:

```
from operator import add
def method (lista, listb):
    return map(add,lista,listb)
```

Comment: Thanks. As a beginner, thoughts on how I would come across zip? That is exactly what I was looking for but I did not see that in the documentation or by google searching.

Comment: There are plenty of online Python courses that walk you through concrete examples. That is generally a good starting point, if you get stuck with an implementation, you can also ask further questions here. I followed this course, but there are plenty more available: https://www.udacity.com/course/data-wrangling-with-mongodb--ud032

Comment: The [built-in functions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html) page of the documentation is worth a read.

Answer (score 0):

The general solution:

```
list_a = [1, 2, 3]
list_b = [5, 7, 9]
list_c = [100, 200, 300]

lists = [list_a, list_b, list_c]

print [sum(k) for k in zip(*lists)] # [106, 209, 312]
```